# Can't upload the latest bootstrap.js to the iGEM wiki

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, bootstrap-4

iGEM (http://2017.igem.org/Main_Page) makes competing teams host their websites with a Media Wiki format. They don't allow any CDNs (even though they don't block it) for CSS and JS, so I have to include these as templates, where you paste the code and then it's put inside the DOM when the page loads.

As I've been using some JS from Bootstrap, I've been uploading it as a template - basically the code between  tags. When I use the CDN, everything works (the scroll spy from Bootstrap), so my code is fine. For some reason, loading it with this template it doesn't work. Loading the Bootstrap CSS does work.

I've also added a console.log at the end of the script and it's not coming up on the console. I've loaded the script in the actual HTML, in the head and before the  tag, but still doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to go around this without using Jquery/pure JS to get it done?

You can look at the page code [here](https://gist.github.com/darksipu/c782eb2f3702f7e64272bdbd0e00453a)!

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: The `<script>` tag should really be just before the closing `</body>` tag instead of in the `<head>` though.

Comment: nope, no error in the console

Answer (score 1):

With the wiki closing dates coming up shortly, I am sure a lot of teams might still be looking for the solution to this. So here goes.

Make a script template file by visiting https://2018.igem.org/Teamplate:Your_Team/script and create the page by editing it. Then put your javascript there **without any surrounding html or script tags**. Save it and go back to the actual page where you want to include this script. In that page, use the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://2018.igem.org/wiki/index.php?title=Template:Your_Team/script&action=raw&ctype=text/javascript"></script>
```

just before your `</body>` tag. That's it, you are done. You can include css files in the same way. Just create a template css file in the exact same fashion as above, then include the `<link>` tag in the head. Don't forget to change `type/javascript' to 'type/css' in both the places as in the given code.

Best of luck for your project!